# count word occurances in a string

Tags: python, string, count

I have the following situation:

```
str='this is the string that Luci want to parse for a dataset uci at web'
word='uci'

str.count(word)=?
```

I want to count only 'uci' which appear independently (not inside any word)
so the output should be 1 and not 2!

Python script required.

Comment: Sounds like homework? What have you tried?

Comment: We don't do homework assignments. Please show us what you have tried or thought of before.

Comment: Post some code and ask for help. Hint - `split` and `Counter` may be useful here.

Comment: I used the following: str.count(word) but this gives me 2 not 1. BTW I gave a simple example to understand the problem better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'this is the string that Luci want to parse for a dataset uci at web'
>>> s.split(' ').count('uci')
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Without giving too much away, you can use `re` to find patterns. In particular, you might look for 'uci' surrounded by word barriers:

```
string = 'this is the string that Luci want to parse for a dataset uci at web'
count = len(re.findall(r'[^\W]uci[\W$]', string))
```

Alternatively, you could split on non-word characters and count the occurrences there:

```
count = re.split(r'\W', string).count('uci')
```

Both of these approaches return 1

Answer (score 1):

```
 def count_words(str):
   words = str.split()
   counts = {}
   for word in words:
    if word in counts:
     counts[word] = counts[word] + 1
    else:
     counts[word] = 1
   return counts

count_words(str)
{'a': 1, 'web': 1, 'string': 1, 'for': 1, 'that': 1, 'this': 1, 'is': 1, 'dataset': 1, 'parse': 1, 'to': 1, 'at': 1, 'want': 1, 'the': 1, 'Luci': 1, 'uci': 1}
```